# UIMenuController.setMenuVisible(_:animated) show the menu but it immediately disappears only after the first time I launch the app

Tags: ios, swift, first-responder, uimenucontroller

I am trying to show a menu.  Right now I am having a problem where the menu shows up and disappears automatically as soon as is show up.  This only happens the first time the code runs after I launch my app. After that it shows up and stays open as expected.

```
self.view.becomeFirstResponder()
let menu = UIMenuController.shared
menu.menuItems = actions // actions is initialized above
menu.setTargetRect(CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 0, height: 0), in: self.view)
menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
```

I was able to get around this problem by putting this code in my viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // other stuff ...

    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: false)

}
```

Because there are no actions and I'm not setting the target rect, it doesn't show anything, but it bipasses the bug that only occurs the first time I call this function.

Does anybody know a more kosher way solve this?

Comment: How do you show this menu controller in your app? Is it by some user action or programmatically in some place? Are you sure that the view can actually be the first responder at the time when you call that code?

Comment: It seems that my problem was only occurring using the simulators. So it's resolved for now I guess.